# Displaying li on top of div? Borders issue

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to build something that I made in photoshop.

I'm trying to get the `<li>` ontop of the border so that it hides the border on the right. (Does that makes sense?)

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5dksT/
Notice when you hover over the `<li>`/link, the right border is shown.

How can I fix this so that each li goes ontop and hides the border? Or is there any other solution you would perform?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a right margin -1px, change the right border color to white.

```
.panel_nav li {
    margin:15px -1px 0 20px;
}
.panel_nav li:hover{
    border-right-color: #fff;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5dksT/5/

Comment: Wouldn't the border color being set to `transparent` be more future proof ?

Answer (score 0):

I added to your `li`...

```
position: relative; 
right: -1px
```

<sup>(or you could change your margin to `15px -1px 0 20px` to pull it `1px` to the right.)</sup>

...and to your `li:hover`...

```
border-right: none;
```

...and it worked!

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/SUMuG/).

Answer (score 0):

Only tested this on Chrome 12 as I'm not at my dev machine at the moment:

Change this:

```
.panel_nav li{list-style:none;padding:10px;margin:15px 0 0 20px;}
```

to:

```
.panel_nav li{list-style:none;padding:10px;margin:15px -1px 0 20px;}
```

and to the end of the li:hover (AFTER the "border:" statement or else it will default to #ccc):

```
border-right: 1px solid #fff;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/waitinforatrain/5dksT/4/

That sets the right margin to negative 1px